# Drag and Drop QFrame

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I've been looking at drag and drop examples and am still puzzled with them. In particular I don't know what to do in mousePressEvent( ) and dropEvent().

I'm following and modifying example which drags and drops QLabel. 
Here is what I think mousePressEvent() should look like for QFrame. I tried it and I can see the frame move but I lose it when I drop it.

```
void SummaryBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QFrame *child = static_cast<QFrame*>(childAt(event->pos()));
    if (!child)
        return;

    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(child);

    QByteArray itemData;
    QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    dataStream << pixmap << QPoint(event->pos() - child->pos());

    QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
    mimeData->setData("application/x-dnditemdata", itemData);

    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
    drag->setHotSpot(event->pos() - child->pos());


    if (drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction, Qt::CopyAction) == Qt::MoveAction) {
        child->close();
    } else {
        child->show();

    }
}
```

Here is dropEvent(). It obviously does not work... not sure why.

```
    void SummaryBar::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        QByteArray itemData = event->mimeData()->data("application/x-dnditemdata");
        QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QPixmap pixmap;
        QPoint offset;
        dataStream >> pixmap >> offset;

        QFrame *newFrame = new QFrame(this);
        //newFrame->setPixmap(pixmap);
        newFrame->move(event->pos() - offset);
        newFrame->show();
        newFrame->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);  
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void SummaryBar::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}    

I would greatly appreciate any help!!
```

Comment: Do you override [`QWidget::dragEnterEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#dragEnterEvent) to accept the proposed drag/drop operation?

Comment: I just added that code to original post. When I try to drag the QFrame it does not always work. It takes few tries before I can actually drag it. Once I drop it it's gone.

Comment: You don't call `acceptProposedAction` if "event->source() == this".

Comment: I took this code from Qt example (draggableicons). There was no acceptProposedAction in that part of the code. I tried adding it and it made no difference.